# NAS storage comparison for Synology vs Overland

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, synology

We are looking for NAS solution that will be used as secondary storage to hold large amount of data.
We have received following proposals that are under our pre allocated budget.

- SnapServer XSR120 / HDD - SnapServer XSR 8TB SATA ENT > QTY: 8 disks 
  for RAID10 / 10g network card / Warranty 1 year
- Synology with 512gb ssd cache (QTY:2) & Seagate 7200 rm Ironwolf >
  QTY 10 disks for RAID10 / 10g network card / Warranty 2 years

What are reviews for overland vs synology in terms of reliability & better integration with active directory?

Answer (score 3):

I give my vote for Synology. It will have better performance because of SSD cache (read or read-write mode). As for AD integration, I haven’t had any issues with it - user friendly GUI where user/group access can be configured.

We are using 2 Synology boxes with active-active replication provided by 3-rd party vsan software. A sample configuration of high available solution -

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/synology-diskstation-ds916-turbocharged-with-starwind-virtual-san

Comment: We are running Active Directory with Single Label Domain. (SLD) like our domain name is ABC (there is no .local or com) . is Synology NAS compatible with the single label domain, can we make it member of SLD domain ?